# load the view using anchor tag to created route

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I have read the [documentation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) before asking question. And also visited the question on related topic but i didn't help.

Here is my anchor tag:

```
<a href="<?= base_url() ?>controller/function/application_title/id">link</a>
```

Example :

```
<a href="<?= base_url() ?>app_job/view_single_job /inventory_control_supervisor/1">link</a>
<a href="<?= base_url() ?>app_job/view_single_job /waste_stream_coordinator/3">link</a>
```

Here is the controller:

```
public function view_single_job($app_title){    
    $id = $this->uri->segment(4);

    $single_app = $this->app_model->get_single_app($id);        
    $this->load->view('app/single_app',['single_app'=>$single_app]);        
}
```

The Route:

```
$route['(:any)/(:num)'] = "controller/function/$1/$2";
```

I want to load the view on click of the anchor tag and which show the url like

```
http://localhost/project/inventory_control_supervisor/1/
http://localhost/project/waste_stream_coordinator/3/
```

The URL is keep changing according to application id.

I am loading the view is that a problem? OR to use routes i must have to use redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your URL in anchor tag

```
<a href="<?= base_url() ?>controller/function/application_title/id">link</a>
                ^             ^         ^              ^         ^
            Base Path   Controller  Method      Argument 01    Argument 02
                            Name     Name
```

But in your controller, you're retrieving only one `public function view_single_job($app_title)`

To catch the data use this

```
public function view_single_job($app_title,$id){ 
    echo $app_title;
    echo $id;
```

---

**But you want to show URL like this** `http://localhost/project/application_title/1/`

for that to have to do like this

```
<a href="<?= base_url() ?>application_title/{id}">link</a>
```

To catch this data use below code in controller

```
public function view_single_job($id){ 
    echo $id;
    $single_app = $this->app_model->get_single_app($id);
```

If you need to remove controller name use this in route

```
$route['application_title/(:num)'] = "app_job/view_single_job/$1";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer sir will try it and get back to you with the result. thanks again.

Comment: Sorry I have edited the question sir, i forget to add application_title in the url which i want.  @AbdullaNilam

Comment: `app_job` is the controller name and function name is `view_single_job`

Comment: Sir application title is the title of each application it will change when application change.

Comment: what didn't get

Comment: i will reply you in a minute sir.

Comment: I have updated the question sir, sorry for not explaining my problem properly.

Comment: thanks sir,  it is clear now that how to route URL. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('controller/function/$1/$2');?>"/>
```

but i am not getting that why are you trying to load view like this on click of a tag give controller's link using `site_url('controllername/function name')`

Comment: sir i get page not found

Answer (score 0):

Try Defining Route:

```
$route['project/(:any)/(:num)'] = 'Controller/view_single_job/$1/$2';
```

being **view_single_job** your function name

And Anchor tag like:

```
<a href='<?=site_url('project/application_title/id'); ?>'>Link</a>
```

While in your controler make id as your 2nd parameter like:

```
public function view_single_job($app_title,$id){ 
    echo $app_title;
    echo $id;
}
```

this will enable you to show your url like
    http://localhost/project/inventory_control_supervisor/1/
here **inventory_control_supervisor** being your application_title and **1** as id.

Comment: Thanks for the answer sir will try it and get back to you with the result. thanks again.

Comment: No Problem, I just checked your updated question try this solution and let me know if this is what you needed.